# ComboBox onBlur to refresh the values of other ComboBoxes using a function

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage with 5 fields on it.  Each field has code in the onBlur event to refresh the values of the ComboBoxes below it.  I now have to add a bunch more fields to this application and I don't want to write the refresh code for each field.  Rather, I would like to create a function that takes a parameter of which field I'm in and do the refresh with a loop.

I can't seem to get this to work.  Below is the code I'm using in the onBlur event.  I don't know the semantics of putting this code in a script library that can access each combobox and call the refresh code in a loop.

Any ideas?

```
<xp:comboBox id="vendorAppAdvSkills1">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="-Select a Category-"
itemValue="-Select a Category-"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent( "vendorAppSkills1" ).getValue();}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:eventHandler event="onblur" submit="false">
<xp:this.script><![CDATA[
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panelVendorAppSkills2}", 
{ 
onComplete: function() 
{ 
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panelVendorAppSkills3}",
{ 
onComplete: function() 
{ 
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panelVendorAppSkills4}",
{ 
onComplete: function() 
{ 
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panelVendorAppSkills5}",
{ 
onComplete: function() 
{ 
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panelNextFinish}",
{ 
} )
}
} )
}
} )
}
} )
}
} );]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have validation on your XPage? If so, validation will be preventing any of the partial refreshes running.

If possible just set the refresh ID of the eventHandler to an area that encompasses all combo boxes. That would just call one partial refresh from the browser to the server.

With your current code you're calling 5 partial refreshes, each time posting the whole content of the browser across to the server, each time updating the whole page, but just pushing back an individual component. Performance is not going to be good, so the single refresh area is better practice (as well as being easier to code!).

As best practice, unless you're preventing validation, also ensure the refresh area includes a Display Errors control. Otherwise your users (including you when testing) will not know if validation has failed.

Comment: I have a table with the first column containing comboboxes I update their values based on the previous selection.  If there are 5 entries in the first one and a user selects nbr 2 I remove nbr 2 from the other comboboxes below then calculate some total values based on the selections.  I thought I had to refresh each combobox's values and the total values on each combobox change.  Hence the partialrefresh on each combobox. I don't refresh the comboboxes or the fields, rather I refresh a panel that contains each combobox and total field. If there is a better way to do this please let me know!!!!

Comment: Because I am using a table, I can only put panels in each <td></td>.  It's very cumbersome thus my reason for wanting to use a function to refresh all the comboboxes and total values on refresh.  I just don't know how to do that other than using the partialrefresh method.  Any advice on how to update the table through a script library function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to update their values (i.e. what's stored in the underlying dominoDocument or other datasource) or their options (i.e. what the user can select from)? If you're updating their values, best practice is to skip the component and update the datasource, and if youur refresh area covers all combo boxes, the values will update. If you're updating the options, compute the options and again, if your refresh area covers all combo boxes, the options will update. If you use an xp:table, you can add an id to it, and use that for the refreshId property of the Partial Refresh

Comment: I am using xp:table so if I add an id and refresh that table can I call that one time and every combo box in the table will refresh?  Rather than what I am doing now calling refresh for each combobox manually?

Comment: Yes, every component within the refresh area will be updated (but also validated)